# JSF 2 Disable Command Button on Click But Re-enable if Validation Fails?

Tags: validation, jsf-2, form-submit

It is easy enough to disable the command button when it is clicked. But say form validation fails (using ajax and without). How can I re-enable the command button if validation fails to allow the user to fix the error and retry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
<h:commandButton disabled="#{myBean.someCondition and not facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

I extended @Daniel's answer to that which worked for me using P:commandButton

```
onclick="this.disabled=true"
oncomplete="this.disabled=
                #{!facesContext.validationFailed}"
                update="@this"
```